# Webdev serve : Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version. No active package webdev

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I want to display my mobile application on the web using Flutter. So, I have done the steps to make it.
But,when use **webdev** serve in command I get an error.

```
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
No active package webdev
```

I attach the photo below:

[image]

How I solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have followed rather outdated instructions. `webdev` is not used anymore.

At the moment, [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) instruction is relevant.

```
 flutter channel beta
 flutter upgrade
 flutter config --enable-web
 flutter create myapp
 cd myapp
 flutter run -d chrome
```

To [add web support](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app) to an existing project, run the following command in a terminal from the root project directory:

```
 flutter create .
```

Comment: Isn't this to make a new project?
I want to display a mobile application that I made before, to become a web

Comment: @FredrickMTPardosi Check this section of the the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app).